# How to open a bottle of wine without a corkscrew?

Tags: wine, serving, drinking, bottles

How can one safely go about opening a bottle of wine when there is no corkscrew present? (Obviously, we are talking corked bottles and not twist-off...)

Comment: Question was also posted on life-hacks some time ago: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/how-can-i-remove-the-cork-from-a-wine-bottle-when-i-dont-have-a-corkscrew

Answer (score 3):

```
-**1.** Use a Screw (the longer the better), a screwdriver, and a hammer. Wrap a small towel around top of bottle and screw. Pry slowly and cautiously the screw out with claw hammer, just like pulling a nail. 
-**2.** Push the cork in with the handle of a wooden spoon, or any blunt object similar in size. 
-**3.** Pump it out. Start with a bike pump and place the pump needle between the cork and the rim of the wine bottle. Pump it three or four times, but be careful because if you pump too much the bottle could explode. After a couple of pumps it cork will jump out or you can pull it out.
-**4.** Twist it out with keys or a serrated knife. 
-**5.**  Wrap the bottle with a towel and use the wall to smack it out. 
-**6.** Slap it out with a shoe, with wine bottle facing horizontal or between your legs facing down to start. 
-**7.** Take a hanger and form it in the shape of a hook with a pair of pliers. Place the new hook on the edge of the cork with the u shape facing up. Wiggle the hook back and forth until it’s about 2 inches down. Rotate the hook so it grabs the bottom of the cork and then begin pulling once it catches the hook.
-**8.** Make a small cut on either side of the cork and find a pair of clean, curved nail scissors or a pair of pliers. Put the nail scissors or pliers into the place the cork was cut and lift.
-**9.** Insert a key, preferably one you have extra copies of, at a 45 degree angle into the cork until most of it is inserted into the cork. Then begin twisting the cork up as pushing up with the key until you get the cork out. Be careful because a weak key has a possibility of breaking.
-**10.** Insert a screw hook into the cork and once sufficiently screwed in, pull. Next time you won’t have to spend so much time searching for a wine opener.
-**11.** Use a string. Tie a figure eight knot and slip it past the cork by wedging it down with a screwdriver or scissors. Once the knot is below the cork, tilt the bottle and then pull the string.
```

Answer (score 2):

A technique that is rarely thought of is to simply push the cork slowly down into the bottle (like with the end of a fork or with a stick,) instead of attempting to pull the cork out of the bottle. (Sometimes this cannot be done safely, however, considering that pushing the cork down into the bottle MAY create more pressure within the bottle and cause it to burst - though I have never seen that happen.)

There is another cool trick, that I have seen though I have not needed to try it personally, where one can use one's own shoe and a hard vertical surface (usually a wall.)

Depicted here (You don't need to speak French to understand this...):

https://youtu.be/pfWu76kyFmw

Comment: Haha I had to do this the other day. DO IT OVER A SINK. Once the cork was finally free the pressure caused red wine to go everywhere

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT risk the alcohol! Push cork slowly into bottle. Use a nail or something metal not a stick. A stick risks the alcohol!